# How to print Hindi charactors in a pdf file using tc pdf

Tags: php, internationalization, tcpdf, hindi

I am making html to pdf file using php tcpdf library.

In my html file there are some words are in Hindi and some are in English. English word showing properly but Hindi showing some '??????'. Please help how to solve this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check below-mentioned examples mentioned in TCPDF website.
URL [for external UTF-8 unicode]: https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_008/

Comment: example 08 is a text file working fine only for text data. but I have data in html format.

Comment: use strip_tags function of php to remove html and store data in $utf8text variable.

Comment: Thanks working now